# When will @egreg reach 654321

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun, users, ducks

> **And the winner is: yo'! Congratulations!**
>
> As prize yo' selected a scout duck with neckerchief:
>
> [image]
>
> (it is already available in the [development version](https://github.com/samcarter8/tikzducks/commit/dac798f62d7efa5f8e1b99dc2782c51ac82d3871) of the tikzducks package and will be included in the next release)

In this little game you have to guess when egreg will reach a reputation of 654321 (or higher) on TeX.Stackexchange.

### Rules

1. Put your guess in an answer (not comment) to this question before 15 January, 2018 (23:59 UTC).
2. The entry with the closest prediction (either + or -) will win.
3. Please add your time as precisely as possible (up to seconds). Missing values for hours/minutes/seconds will be replaced by 0.
4. If two entries state the exact same date and time, the one posted first will be considered.
5. Unless otherwise stated, all answers are assumed to be UTC (if you answer in some other time, it would be nice if you would already include a translation into UTC). The frame of references is Earth, exposing @egreg to time dilation (putting him on a rocket to Alpha Centauri, tuning his bike...) will not change anything.
6. Only one answer per user.
7. Contestants must have been a member of TeX.SE before 26 December, 2017.
8. @egreg is not allowed to participate (sorry :), but of course you can add an answer for fun!
9. I am excluded as well, my answer below is just for fun.
10. Time lords in possession of a working Tardis are also excluded.
11. Participants are disqualified if they offer a bounty specifically for @egreg - this means if someone offers a bounty to attract attention to a question and @egreg answers it, that's fine, offering a bounty to reward an existing answer from @egreg is also fine, you just cannot win this contest.
12. the winner will only be announced a day after @egreg reached this reputation, just in case some serial upvoting or similar will be corrected.

> 13. Don't change your voting behaviour because of this contest - don't try any serial voting for @egreg. This would not help, as @egreg is [reputation capped](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) most days anyway and serial voting is automatically reversed by the site!

14. Any legal action is precluded.

### Prize

The winner may wish an addition to the [tikzducks package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks). For example a new accessories, some kind of hat, clothing, a duck based on you or your avatar ... (I reserve the right to reject a wish because of moral scruples).

[image]

### Currently submitted entries

Format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

- 2018-03-14 15:09:26 RobtAll
- 2018-04-01 19:00:00 Tobia Tesan
- 2018-04-20 11:10:28 (corey979)
- 2018-05-01 11:23:47 Sigur
- 2018-05-04 16:04:04 CarLaTeX
- 2018-05-05 17:05:00 marmot
- 2018-05-06 03:14:15 (samcarter)
- 2018-05-06 19:04:03 mrclary
- 2018-05-07 07:05:18 BMWurm
- 2018-05-08 08:15:32 Paulo Cereda
- 2018-05-12 12:34:56 Ulrike Fischer
- 2018-05-13 07:12:00 (swarm intelligence)
- 2018-05-13 14:55:25 thewaywewalk
- 2018-05-17 10:52:00 Alan Munn
- 2018-05-17 14:58:36 anderstood
- 2018-05-18 08:05:08 yo'
- **2018-05-19 15:44:38 egreg crossed the 654321 threshold**
- 2018-05-22 23:55:42 koppor
- 2018-05-23 12:00:00 Werner
- 2018-05-23 22:59:39 Axel Sommerfeldt
- 2018-05-25 18:57:00 Sverre
- 2018-06-01 00:00:00 Raoul Kessels
- 2018-09-08 08:13:32 A Feldman
- 2019-01-01 00:00:00 David Carlisle
- ????-??-?? ??-??-?? (egreg)

---

After excluding the first and last two entries the mean value is MJD 58251.3 -> let's see if swarm intelligence really works :)

[image]

---

*(please tell me if I missed anything obvious in the rules section -- this is my first contest)*

Comment: How about shifting the target to 654323, which is a prime number?

Comment: @marmot Good idea, however as this prediction started in chat some while ago, I'd like to stick with the nice number sequence.

Comment: I'm ROFL, great idea! I'll do some calculations and answer :)

Comment: @marmot I prefer 654321, too: the goal is nearer :)

Comment: I think this will encourage serial voting when he gets close to the value.  No matter what it will encourage voting for the person not the answers (the fact that the answers are independently worth voting for is irrelevant.)

Comment: @AlanMunn serial voting will not work as egreg is rep capped most days.

Comment: But quickly after obtaining 654321 he will reach 666666. Sodom and Gomorrah! ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke In the early ages of the site, it must have survived 66666, so I am optimistic about 666666 :)

Comment: I think that a rule shall be added that participants cannot reward @egreg a bounty after January 15th.

Comment: @yo' I think this is too general. Imagine a bounty to attract attention to a question, egreg answers and even if the OP does not award the bounty to egreg, the system will auto-award half of the bounty. That's why I formulated rule #11 that no targeted bounty is allowed.

Comment: re rule "14, Any legal action is precluded.", does this imply that only illegal actions are permitted?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Maybe you can help with this. I was looking for some way to express the German phrase "Der Rechtsweg ist ausgeschlossen" which is commonly added to contests to prevent people from suing the organisation if they did not win. Any suggestions?

Comment: @samcarter -- oh, i was just being a nuisance.  <grin>  i know this really means that no lawsuits are permitted in case of disagreement.  the judge's decision is final.  i think the concept is great (if a bit silly).  but that's the ethos of this group.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your reply! I was really insecure about this phrase as many different translations seem to exist and I changed it quite a few times during drafting.

Comment: ooh I can sue people if I don't win? Interesting...

Comment: @PauloCereda no :) well, maybe. I don't know which laws apply to ducks :)

Comment: A "ducky defendant"  indeed.

Comment: Using my previous interpolation I tried to predict when egreg would get 634,062 points (its present rep) and I got... 23 Feb. 2018 (01:53)  `:-)`.

Comment: @anderstood :) That looks promising!

Comment: I guess @RobtAl wins?

Comment: @TobiaTesan We'll see...

Comment: @samcarter sorry, I'm an idiot, I misread the actual number :|

Comment: @samcarter It seems that tomorrow (May 19) is the day, but I'll be touring, so I'll see the winner in the evening.

Comment: @egreg Weather forecast looks good - have fun on your tour! I already looking forward to the decryption of your own guess!

Comment: @egreg In case you'd like to try a precision landing, please feel free to downvote one of my answer tomorrow morning (today would not work because of your rep cap, would it?)

Comment: @samcarter Next goal might be 777777, but no less than 16 months from now.

Comment: @egreg I'm looking forward to it!

Comment: @user49915 No less than six months for 777777 and about three years for 1M.

Comment: @user49915 I think just repeating the same contest with a different number might be a bit boring - maybe someone comes up with a new idea?

Comment: @user49915 How to make sure that this does not influence the voting of people? For egreg my argument was that he is anyway rep-capped more often than not, which does not really work for David

Comment: @user49915 The interest of folks in their reputation is no point to worry about. What might be more problematic is that such a contest might influence the people to vote more or less for a user. If this user is rep capped, this won't have much effect (it might still screw the number of votes for individual post...), but if the user is not rep capped, this would influence the total reputation of this user, something I don't want to mess with.

Comment: @user49915 A downvote won't influence the total rep  if someone is rep-capped. Same for additional upvotes.

Comment: @user49915 most days. You can look up the time this contest ran at https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Comment: @user49915 Side-effect of being a tex god?

Comment: @user49915 Reputation is pretty useless once you have earned 50 and the right to comment everywhere, so it does not really make a difference if one gets some points or not

Comment: @user49915 unfortunately not everybody thinks like this - especially not stackexchange itself.

Comment: Great idea! I just found this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 18-05-18 08:05:08 UTC

Comment: Please let us know which is your request about `tikzducks`!

Comment: Congratulations!!!

Comment: @CarLaTeX If you follow the chat, it's obvious. If not, you'll have to wait until the release :-)

Comment: @yo' I follow the chat :):):)

Answer (score 32):

Like Renaissance mathematicians did, I'll give my guess in encrypted form so as not to influence other participants. I expressed my guess in the format YYYY-MM-DD and issued

```
echo ZZZZZZ YYYY-MM-DD | shasum -a 256
```

where `ZZZZZZ` is my old landline phone number (six digits) getting the fingerprint

```
8ab685f7a789f83d8c79f770e8c085be847a99b2c0feb574ca81e06771f354d1
```

This is to make it useless to type in all dates in order to get a matching SHA256 checksum.

When the contest will be finished, I'll reveal my guess, so anybody can check the matching of the data with the checksum. The old phone number cannot be used any longer, so it will be irrelevant information when revealed.

#### UPDATE 2018-05-19

It turns out I was a bit optimistic in my estimate:

```
655401 2018-05-13
```

Congratulations to yo' for being the winner!

Comment: Thank you for joining the fun! Great idea to encrypt your guess!

Comment: WHERE ARE MY RAINBOW TABLES? Time for some duck computations. `:)`

Comment: @egreg Uh, you're right, that wasn't very nice of me. I'm sorry. Keep in mind to not underestimate modern computing power next time. I should've posted your guess hashed with the phone number reversed instead: `8c327d8fd72f490cdb0b6b363e6105693f1c23bcc191fb13951e90ec83579e8c`. Figuring this out was fun. I didn't expect the actual cracking to take 13 seconds, to be honest.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Cracking it knowing precisely the format is of course very easy.

Comment: @NieDzejkob: thankfully phone numbers and dates have a very restrict range of possible symbols. `:)`

Comment: Your intelligence gives exactly the same result as the _swarm intelligence_...

Comment: Since people can no longer participate. Will you post your answer? Or will you wait until you have reached the goal?

Answer (score 19):

I think he will never get to the target in 2018 due to several thousand questions about `%` at end of line being reclassified as duplicates and deleted resulting in a loss of most of his Rep.

If I win I think the tikzducks should be re-implemented in picture mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for participating! Oh, the football is even in colour - fancy!

Comment: @samcarter it's not a _football_ it's a ham and pineapple pizza, in honour of egreg!

Comment: Oh, please excuse my inexperience in high art :) The pizza of course makes perfect sense!

Comment: @samcarter How could you miss this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390382/101651 to the `tikzduck` question!

Comment: @CarLaTeX :) Somehow I only remembered the picture mode football duck from this answer - my subconsciousness must have erased the pineapple pizza - too traumatic to remember!

Comment: Somebody want's to be number 1? I would totally use that duck everywhere!

Answer (score 15):

Based on [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/775343) and linear extrapolation, it should be

> May 13th, 2018, 14:55:25

Comment: Thank you for participating! Oh, let's see if science is right!

Comment: What has science ever done for us? */sent from my smartphone* `:)`

Answer (score 12):

> 2018/05/05 05:05 pm

... because that's when the marmots awake from hibernation ;-)

Comment: ooh advanced hibernation techniques from the marmot society! `:)`

Comment: Thank you for participating! A really good reason to choose the date :) I am just wondering how you added this answer during hibernation :)

Comment: @samcarter: ooh marmot mysteries

Comment: @samcarter Hibernating for 8 months can be boring, so I play with LaTeX once in a while ;-)

Comment: @marmot Oh, that explains it :)

Answer (score 11):

May 23, 2018 at around 12:00 noon.

---

This is the cumulative, annual reputation of @egreg, post 2011 (the first year of joining):

- 2011: 54,140
- 2012: (+ 92,699; +71.2%) 146,839
- 2013: (+ 98,357; +6.1%) 245,196
- 2014: (+ 97,496; -0.9%) 342,692
- 2015: (+ 96,697; -0.8%) 439,389
- 2016: (+ 92,547; -4.3%) 531,936
- 2017: (+ 88,897; -3.9%) 620,833

[image]

I used the top-ranked 2D function suggestion via [ZunZun's function finder](http://zunzun.com/):

```
y = c * atan(exp((x-a)/b)) + Offset

Fitting target of lowest sum of squared absolute error = 2.0467080344324614E+05

a =  2.0128116742956618E+03
b =  8.0055160074372509E+00
c =  1.5744218139080477E+06
Offset = -1.0100039377450938E+06
```

Solving for `y = 654321` yielded a solution of `x = 2017.3933394731732`, or halfway into [day 144 of 2018](https://www.epochconverter.com/days/2018). This lies somewhere between May 23rd and 24th (2018).

Comment: Wow, very scientific, and we discover he has a decreasing trend during the last years!

Comment: Did you consider the loss of reputation due to deletion of user P. in February 2017?

Comment: Thank you for participating! I am crossing my fingers, science has to proof right!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: No. The minimum rep-per-day since 2012 has never seemed to that low.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer who is/was user P. (never heard of him, but if he can lower egregs reputation with deleting his account, he must've been busy around here)?

Comment: @Skillmon: A user named Papiro ;-) He was an avid voter, but had not much reputation profile (about 3k, if I remember correctly( though, as such, his votes were lost. My reputation was cut by roughly 5500 then

Answer (score 8):

> Saturday, 12 May (2018 naturally), 12:34:56

If I win I want a vampire duck

[image]

May the royal flush magic do its work!

[image]

Comment: oooh das Vampirente!

Comment: Wow! Now I know what to do for Halloween! (in case you do not win, then it will of course come sooner :)

Comment: Because I like the idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFE3v.png

Comment: @samcarter neat ;-) the background should perhaps be a bit lighter.

Answer (score 8):

## `1525767332`

Since I already know I am going to win, you can start working on my prize: I want a EG duck to rival our DPC duck. `:)`

Comment: Thank you for participating! Quack!

Comment: @samcarter: thanks for the great game! Quack! `<3`

Comment: You can have your prize right away: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\definecolor{egreg}{RGB}{171,196,163}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \duck[]
 \fill[egreg] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
\end{tikzpicture} 
 
\end{document}`

Comment: @samcarter the motorbike is missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The bike will be delivered upon winning the contest :)

Answer (score 8):

My guess: April 1st, 2018, 19:00:00 UTC.

Just in case some well thought out April fools' joke gains the guy a reputation boost.

Comment: I think you could find this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361547/how-to-draw-a-fish interesting

Answer (score 8):

The majority seems to be very sure that it will happen in May, but since I am in Chemistry and lower temperature gives lower reaction rates, the winter should slow down the daily reputation increase ;-).
So I will place my guess a bit ahead:

2018-06-01 00:00:00

Comment: Thank you for participating! Interesting idea! On the other hand winter is not ideal for bike tours - so maybe reputation gain is actually faster during winter?

Comment: Good point. We shall see!

Comment: I wish I were a chemist, so I'd dedicate my research to making things explode all the time. `:)` *ZE GOOGLES, ZEY DO NOTHING!*

Answer (score 8):

My guess is:

2018-05-23 22:59:39 UTC

(assuming egrep will earn an average rep. of 234 per day)

Comment: Is "egrep" a Freudian slip? :-)

Comment: @Mico: worst: it's a command line tool! `:)`

Answer (score 8):

I stored egreg's last 90 days rep ([from this page source](http://view-source:https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=reputation&sort=graph)), then used *Mathematica* commands:

```
fit = FindFit[data, a*t + b, {a, b}, t]
Show[ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
     Plot[a*t + b /. fit, {t, 0, Length@data}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]]
```

That gives the following plot (data in red, fit in dashed blue)

[image]

and date:

```
n = -Length@data + (654321 - b)/a /. fit;
DatePlus[DateObject[{2018, 1, 5}, TimeZone -> 0], n]
```

> 2018-05-17 14:58:36

Also, `2 StandardDeviation[Differences[data]]/Sqrt[n]` returns about `6`, so, assuming the daily rep follows a normal distribution, the 95% confidence interval is plus or minus 6 days.

Comment: Thanks for participating! Your estimate will be a tight race with https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7499/36296!

Comment: @samcarter Indeed. I posted a question on [MMA.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163119/predicting-when-a-se-user-will-reach-a-given-rep), might be worth asking in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) too... Actually I find the prediction problem very interesting!

Comment: Oh, it would be interesting to hear what Cross Validate would have to say about this problem! Can you please ping me when you get an answer on MMA.se?

Comment: @samcarter Sure. [In the meanwhile...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321751/predict-when-a-se-user-will-reach-a-given-reputation)

Comment: Thanks! Interesting answers!  I am curious how good the predictions will turn out.

Comment: @samcarter Yes, mine wasn't really a guess, but was based on a similar calculation but with 450 days worth of data.

Comment: @AlanMunn I myself used a crude fit to the small graph on the top left of his reputation page :)

Answer (score 7):

As approximately stated in https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=40710281#40710281 my guess is

> Sunday, 6 May 2018, 03:14:15 am (UTC)

Answer (score 7):

May the Force be with egreg!

> Friday, 4 May 2018, 04:04:04 pm (UTC)

If I win, I would like to have a girlfriend, or, better, a female-duck-friend, for Herr Professor Paulinho van Duck.

Comment: Nice choice! Thanks for participating!

Comment: @samcarter Yay! :):):) I thought that he could earn more reputation at the beginning of the year rather than in the Summer... So the per day average is higher...

Answer (score 7):

My guess is:

> May 17, 2018 10:52:00

Answer (score 7):

Since I don't know if there is some limit for daily reputation I am not able to try to predict.

So I'll answer just for fun (and of course based on some other people's vote).

> 2018-05-01 11:23:47

Comment: Thank you for participating! About the daily maximum, see the 3rd paragraph of https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation (beware of the exceptions).

Comment: @samcarter, so this is how people are predicting and choosing next May... lol

Comment: There are also different approaches, see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7502/36296

Comment: I chose May because I was lazy enough to perform any calculations. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

Obviously 2018-03-14 15:09:26, Using 09 instead of 92.

Comment: If you round instead of truncating, that becomes 15:09:2**7**. I hope that won't make you loose the first prize.

Comment: @anderstood What, are there more digits to pi ? I can only count to 8 digits, because I need my other two fingers for typing.

Answer (score 6):

Using [anderstood's](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7518/151941) `data` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163119/predicting-when-a-se-user-will-reach-a-given-rep) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321751/predict-when-a-se-user-will-reach-a-given-reputation), I used *Mathematica*'s `FindFormula`:

```
data2 = Transpose@{Range[Length@data], data};
ff = FindFormula[data2, x, 10]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@{ff[[2 ;; 10]], 654321}, {x, 1500, 1650}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
pred = Table[x /. FindRoot[ff[[i]] == 654321, {x, 1560}], {i, 2, 10}]
ListPlot[pred, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {2, 10}]
```

[image]

```
time = Mean@pred - Length@data
```

to get

```
DatePlus[DateObject[{2018, 1, 5}, TimeZone -> 0], time]
```

> Fri 20 Apr 2018 11:10:28 GMT

Comment: *2018 (comments must be at least 15 characters in length)

Comment: I get 20 Apr 2018 11:10:23 with my answer, but using all data points instead of the last 90. Not too different!

Comment: Thank you for participating and welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Unfortunately you do not fulfil rule #7, so I added your answer in `()` -> you're more than welcome to see how good your prediction is, but some other participant will be declared winner. (we can of course negotiate some consolation prize in case you have the best forecast :)

Comment: @samcarter No, no, I didn't read the rules carefully, just jumped into computations. So I'll just see what will the answer be. In case my guess turns out to be not-so-bad, an honorary mention would be enough :)

Comment: @corey979 We'll see when the time comes :)

Comment: Very nice to see how people are working hard to try to answer a so simple question.... lol Very cool your post.

Answer (score 6):

Using anderstood's data, I noticed that egreg consistently required about 120 days from Jan 4 to increase is reputation by 32289 for each of the first 3 years; last year was an outlier at 128 days. You see, one has to consider seasonal effects ;)

I'm going with 2018-05-06 19:04:03, 121.79 days after Jan 5 00:00:00

Comment: Nice! I had not seen any periodic seasonal effects, even though I checked (including after smoothening).

Comment: Thank you for participating! Just a few hours from my own guess :)

Comment: The residual fit [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1JIM.png) does not display seasonal effects (image from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163171/18767)).

Answer (score 5):

My guess is: 2018-09-08 08:13:32

Comment: Thank you for participating! And a happy new year!

Answer (score 5):

> 2018-05-22 23:55:42

This date diff between beginning of [JabCon](https://jabcon.jabref.org/) and that date is 106 if one includes start and end date. I plan to have published [JabRef](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/jabref/info) [4.2](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/milestone/17) on that date. 100 days is the normal time one allows to settle down (like governments). 100 + 4 + 2 = 106. 23:55 is [5 minutes before twelve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Clock).

The [scientific-thesis-template](http://latextemplates.github.io/scientific-thesis-template/) contains two (out of 16) questions, where egreg took part (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50638/9075, [How to display cover page alone in the "two page view" mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21097/how-to-display-cover-page-alone-in-the-two-page-view-mode/21109#21109)). 2+16 are the seconds missing to midnight. Thus, 60 - (2+16) forms the seconds.

Comment: It would be much more fun if you would have found some far fetched connection between your advertisement and your guess :(

Comment: Mea culpa. I updated the answer.

Comment: Great explanation! Good luck for your guess and thank you for participating!

Answer (score 3):

- Looking at the other answers so far, there seemed to be a strong
  consensus for it happening in **May**, so I went with that.
- The **7th** wasn't yet taken, so I thought I'd pick that one.
- For the **time** only a palindrome could ever be correct, so it picked itself:

---

```
 (20)   18-05-07 07:05:18    (,02 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

May 25, 2018, 18:57 UTC. (extra characters here)

Comment: And when will Sverre reach 9999?

Comment: @anderstood Can't you please estimate that with your math skills as you did for egreg? `:)`