# English pangrams with ducks

Tags: discussion, ducks

There have already been several examples of trivialities, here, apropos ducks, and I think that this one is not much worse than others…

## Motivation

This evening I saw an ad on this site from [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/): it was screaming something like (I don’t remember exactly) “We feature quick foxes… Sleazy dogs…”, and, all of a sudden, it hit me that **no mention at all was made of ducks!**  I’m becoming so biased in this regard that I felt immediately compelled to invent a pangram involving ducks, to be used for displaying the full set of lowercase letters in a font.  Unfortunately, my limited English vocabulary didn’t permit me to go any further than

> The jumping yellow duck quacks from the overfull horizontal box.

(actually, I didn’t try that hard!), which is 54 character long, so I thought of seeking help from my friendly fellows at TeX.SX!

## Question and Rules

The question is to find a short English sentence that:

- makes sense;
- contains all the 26 English *lowercase* letters (the first letter
  of the sentence must be uppercase, so it does not count,
  nor does any other letter in the sentence that must be
  capitalized according to the rules of the English grammar);
- makes explicit mention of ducks, not necessarily as the subject
  of the sentence; note, however, that the word “duck” must refer
  to the bird (so, for instance, using the verb “to duck” doesn’t
  suffice, in itself, to comply with this rule);
- contains at least an implicit, but clearly recognizable, reference
  to (La)TeX (*e.g.*, the “overfull horizontal box”, in our example).

The shortest sentence wins.

### Clarification about the rules

After seeing a few answers, I think there are a couple of points that should be clarified:

1. Using explicitly the words “TeX” or “LaTeX” as references to the
   (La)TeX world breaks what is perhaps the most important rule about
   word puzzles: in a riddle on the checkerboard, you cannot use
   the word “checkerboard”; but in any case, we all agree upon the
   rule that those words—*when referring to (La)TeX*—**must** be
   capitalized in the “usual unusual” way, so they would only make you
   gain a couple of vowels.  Of course, you can still mention
   Tex Willer… ;-)
2. [One could argue](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/english-pangrams-with-ducks/7652?noredirect=1#comment23032_7650)
   that mentioning ducks is, in itself, a reference to TeX:
   well, no, your answer must contain a reference *independent* of ducks
   (and also of marmots)!

## Comment

On second thought, perhaps this *is* the most stupid question ever asked here, even restricting to those concerning ducks!

Comment: Does `\duckumentklas{article}` count?

Comment: @percusse: The answer should be an English sentence, not LaTeX code. :-)

Comment: I can type anything english after that

Comment: @percusse: Mmmh, mentioning ducks and alluding to LaTeX at the same time, with “duck” appearing as a substring of another word…  I had not thought of this possibility.  I’d say that this violates the rules because of the substring, but let me see if the resulting phrase is sufficiently witty to entice me into making an exception!

Comment: @GuM That's not (standard) LaTeX code either .... Isn't a reference to ducks on this site already an implicit reference to LaTeX?

Comment: ‘A blitzed margin!’ crows a jinxed hop of quivery drakes. 44

Comment: `abfghjlmnpqrtvwxyz` is duck code. 28

Comment: @cfr: I plainly admit I had to turn to a dictionary in order to understand your first answer.  I have two remarks: (1) if the reference to TeX lies in the “blitzed margin”, I’m afraid it is a bit too weak; (2) why not just “…quivery **ducks**”?  And, yes, I’m also afraid your second answer is cheating…! (;-)

Comment: Is this why a duck showed up in the lower right corner this morning?  I'm currently running a virus scan to see if it is just me.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I see that duck too.  I think it is a nice addition that has just been made to the site by its administrators!  And, no, the fact that it happened after this question has been posted is only a coincidence… :-)

Comment: The real scandal is that neither ducks nor marmots are mentioned!

Comment: Neither of my comments were posted as answers. Nor were they intended as such. And why not 'quivery drakes'? Hens would not be quivery, after all :-).

Comment: @marmot Ducks aren't mentioned in what? Confused. Marmots point is fair. Lack of cats is also disturbing. And no donkeys at all.

Comment: Re. (1) your criterion was too weak. Clearly it is 'recognizable' since you know that is the reference to TeX. That's all the fourth of your desiderata requires as stated. If something stronger is desired, please edit your question to clarify the precise strength needed to fit your workflow.

Comment: WORD OF THE WEEK: PANGRAM *I thought it could be a dessert `:)`*

Comment: We need a UTF8/16/32-based pangram, in which *all symbols* of the Unicode range are used in a sentence.

Comment: @cfr: and hwyadens too. `:)`

Comment: @cfr: You must agree that I wouldn’t have recognized “margin” as a reference to TeX, if i hadn’t known that the sentence was supposed to contain one.  More precisely, I asked specifically for a reference to *TeX*, not to typography in general.  But you say you didn’t want to answer, so this remark is likely to be pointless… :-)

Comment: Not to be a killjoy, but this is completely off-topic. (Meta is really for questions about the workings of the tex.stackexchange website.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Fully agreeing here with you. Please go to area51 and ask for a duck.SE. This place should be about TeX/LaTeX and in particular this meta about this TeX/LaTeX page running.

Comment: @Johannes_B: OK, but then, is [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7493/69818) on topic?  I’m not trying to make an argument of it, but, you know, TeX guys have their particular attitude; many of us share a background in mathematics and a passion for computer science, so we are just… well, particular.  I’m afraid that if you want a TeX.SE in which many true TeX enthusiasts spend their time, you have to accept the fact that this people simply cannot stay serious all the time… :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B: On second thought, I must agree that this question is objectively off-topic and should be closed; on the other hand, I don’t want to look tactless to those users who have upvoted it and ungrateful to those who spent their time to answer.  So, this is want I’m going to do: I’ll vote to close this question as off-topic, and let other user’s votes decide whether to approve this.

Comment: @GuM Is 'horizontal box' indicative of TeX, if you aren't looking for it? I'd think it would mean a coffin to most folk - and certainly not in the expl3 sense!

Comment: This question is not related to the site or TeX/LaTeX at all.  Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @GuM You could change the challange to include creating a good `panagram` environment (or another way of presenting panagrams, maybe a `font catalouge` package) and posted on the main page (tagging it with `documentation`[if that exists] and `fun`) it would be on topic. But I don't see why it's on meta (with the purposes I've described it would also serve as a showpiece, showing font's and LateX code to new people)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one with 36 letters:

> A jovial duck with zany plumage foxes breqn.

This is like code golf but for words. Here's one with 34 letters:

> A jive duck with zany plumage foxes breqn.

This is now <s>the same length as</s> one shorter than the classic one.

Comment: Quite *good!*  There is only one problem (which, admittedly, I hadn’t thought of when I asked the question): usually we write the names of packages in a different typeface than normal text, typically in `\ttfamily` or in `\sffamily`; this would imply that your sentence wouldn’t be appropriate for displaying all lowercase letters of a given font.

Comment: @GuM Oh come on! That's really splitting hairs. Typeface doesn't change the fact that the letters are the letters. And this is a *bona fide* reference to LaTeX.  Next think you'll be telling us that using tex or latex in the sentence doesn't count either since they should be rendered LaTeX and TeX, so that the upper case letters don't count.

Comment: Yes, TeX and LaTeX should be capitalized as usual, but, apart from this, it would be preferable that the reference be not so explicit.  The spirit of the question is to find a witty variant of the classical “The quick brown fox…” that mention ducks while, at the same time, *alluding* to TeX…

Comment: @GuM Well I'm glad I didn't use them, then. :)

Comment: The classic one has 34 *lowercase* letters: yours is actually one letter shorter!

Comment: The Oxford dictionary for marmots does not know about the word "breqn". ;-)

Comment: @marmot `alias OED='texdoc'`

Comment: 'tis still inglish 'innit?

Comment: @GuM That objection seems ill-conceived for the reason Alan Munn gave. I expected your objection to be that the sentence is not English because it isn't.

Comment: @cfr Of course it's English. Package names are names, and names are arbitrary strings. And package names by convention (unlike proper names of people) are not capitalized, since they are case-sensitive when used.  So this is no different from the sentence "A jive duck with zany plumage foxes Bob" which is, of course, English.

Comment: @AlanMunn But then I think some of the rejected suggestions in the comments on the question should be permitted, too.

Comment: @cfr Your duck code example was very clever, but different in an important way I think: names are also conventionalized, so `breqn` is a name, but `abfghjlmnpqrtvwxyz` is something else.  But this is all supposed to be fun...so I have no stake in this really.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, I thought you'd say that. However, I call Humpty Dumpty as an expert witness for the defence who will attest that a word means what I decide it means. By extrapolation, I will then argue that an arbitrary string means what I decide it means. I will then call a computer to show that 'words' are simply arbitrary strings with meanings. Drawing the obvious inferences, the defence will then rest its case.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a shorter sentence myself:

> Ducks wearing pyjamas squeezed into an overfull hbox.

It contains 44 lowercase letters.  By comparison, the usual

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

has 34 lowercase letters.

---

**Edit:** One letter shorter:

> Eight ducks with pyjamas squeezed in an overfull box.

Also, removed jargon (“hbox”)‚

---

**2nd Edit:** 40 lowercase letters:

> Eighty-two ducks jump squeezed in an overfull box.

This is something one could try to illustrate with the help of the `tikzduck` package…

Comment: I don't think the last one is grammatical. But you could save a character in the earlier one by deleting the 'd' in 'squeezed'.

Answer (score 2):

**REVISION**: A bit longer but with a marmot (and reference to latex):

> Marmot vows to help best friend quacking tikz duck enjoy latex.

And for those with access to Mathematica: here is a short script that might help prevent you from getting mad.

```
mystring = 
  "Marmot vows to help best friend quacking tikz duck enjoy latex.";
Complement[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 
 Union[StringPartition[mystring, 1]]]
```

Comment: And the reference to TeX is 'lynx' with the 'n' removed?

Comment: @AlanMunn Not, it's the duck and the marmot. ;-)

Comment: No, there must be a reference to TeX which is *independent* of ducks and marmots.

Comment: @GuM Wait, TeX without ducks and marmots? Isn't that something very boring and sad? ;-) (BTW +1 to your answer.)

Comment: I hate to be that fussy, but “latex” should be written “LaTeX”, according to a well-known and long-established rule of English grammar; and we said that uppercase letters don’t count… ;-)

Comment: And TikZ for that matter. (Not that I agree...).

Comment: @AlanMunn: But at least, TikZ is not like the word “checkerboard” used in a riddle on the checkerboard…

Comment: @GuM Yes, but you can refer to `latex` the executable or the format, rather than LaTeX, the whole caboodle, so this really isn't a problem. The executable doesn't need caps anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is perfectly grammatical (or if it makes much sense), but here is a attempt with 40 letters and no jargon:

> eight squab latex ducks improve frozen jetways